# Making a cylinder with bumps on it

Tags: modeling, animation, objects

[image]

[image]

I am trying to make a animated Cilantro character, and need to make the sides of the cilantro bundle by adding bumps. But I don't know how to do it without making individual pieces and stick them onto the cylinder. I also want to make cilantro hair, any advice on that is a bonus. I am new to Blender and just want to learn. I added pictures of the reference and what I am trying to do without making individual lines. I want those lump/bump to be from the cylinder instead on me making 50 duplicates and pasting them into the spots like I did in the picture.

Comment: Can you show some references that you have in mind(Pictures)?

Comment: don't you want to fake the stripes with a bump or normal map?

Comment: You could subdivide the edges of the circles, then select all the long edges, then use checker deselect to select only the redundant long edges produced by the subdivision, and then scale along XY.